# Why does countable compactness imply compactness on metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

By "$E$ is countably compact", I mean that every countable open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover.  By "$E$ is compact", I mean that every open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover. Let $M$ be a metric space.  Prove that if a subset $E$ of $M$ is countably compact, then it is compact.

I am looking for a proof that just uses the machinery of metric space topology, and doesn't appeal to general topological spaces, if this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is tied in to a standard set of compactness results for metric spaces.  Here the usual sequence of equivalent properties is as follows:

- Countable compactness
- Limit point compactness (every infinite set has a limit point)
- Sequential compactness (every sequence has a convergent subsequence)
- Compactness

These are all equivalent for metric spaces.  I'm afraid I don't know off the top of my head a more direct proof than proving the chain of implications one at a time.  I checked in Munkres, which proves that the latter three are equivalent (which should be in any standard text), and the only thing remaining to show is the implication (countable compactness) $\implies$ (limit point compactness), which uses the following modified argument.

You must prove that every set $A$ without limit points is finite.  We can assume that $A$ is countable without loss of generality (If every countably infinite set has a limit point, then all infinite sets have limit points).  Now for each element $a\in A$, there is a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ containing no other points of $A$ (since $a$ is not a limit point of $A$).  Since $A$ contains all of its limit points tautologically, $A$ must be closed, which in turn implies that $A$ is countably compact.  Therefore the cover $\{U_a\}$ has a finite subcover, implying that $A$ is finite.

Comment: It’s no more direct, but one can bypass sequential compactness: limit point compact implies totally bounded, which implies separable, which implies second countable, which implies Lindelöf.

Comment: Your proof seems good, except it doesn't make sense to show that $A$ is closed, therefore countably compact, when countable compactness is already assumed.  However, I was looking for some intuition as to why countable compactness implies compactness, and this intuition is kind of obscured through the chain of implications: Countable Compactness $\Rightarrow$ Limit Point Compactness $\Rightarrow$ Sequential Compactness $\Rightarrow$ Compactness.  Is there any way of doing this more directly, or at least explaining an intuition for it?

Comment: We need to show that our set $A \subset E$ is countably compact assuming that $E$ is countably compact.  As to the intuition, I would also be interested in seeing something less formal.

Comment: It is not always true that $A$ contains all of it's limit points. Consider a sequence in $E=[0,1]$. Then $A$, the sequence itself, is infinite but doesn't have a limit point.

Comment: In the argument we were assuming that $A$ was a set without any limit points.